# Are ASP.NET 4 Webforms Cross Browser compatible?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, cross-browser

This article suggests it is:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3k2ssx2(v=vs.100).aspx

Is this correct or are there limitations documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is cross browser compatible. The first section of the same link gives you the answer:

> Different browsers, and different versions of the same browser,
>   support different features. ASP.NET server controls will automatically
>   determine the browser that has requested the page and render the
>   appropriate markup for that browser. **However, some control features
>   cannot be rendered on older browsers**, so it is a good idea to look
>   at the output of your pages on as many browser types as you can to
>   make sure that the pages are presented to all browsers the way you
>   want them to be.

So as stated above you need to check in as many browsers as you can to check if any of the control is breaking in any browser. I don't think you can get any such list documented anywhere but information reported by different people as to what is breaking for them on which browser.